# Activerecord doesn't find record created with CSV info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, csv, fastercsv

When I create Records from a CSV file, Activerecord can't find them with `Record#find_by`. If I create a Record through the rails console, it works as expected. Here's my code for creating through CSV:

```
def create
  file = params[:record][:file].tempfile

  CSV.foreach file, :headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol do |row|
    Record.create row.to_hash
  end

  redirect_to records_url
end
```

Here are some examples from the console:

```
> Record.find_by_email "matching@asd.asd" 
=> nil     # Should return record created through the CSV file

> Record.create :email => "matching@asd.asd"
> Record.find_by_email "matching@asd.asd"
=> <Record id: 4, email: "matching@asd.asd">
> Record.find_all_by_email "matching@asd.asd"
=> [<Record id: 4, email: "matching@asd.asd">]    # Should return both
```

Any help would be appreciated. I'm on Rails 3.1rc5 if it matters.

-

**Updated with `rows.to_hash` output**

As requested, the output from debugging rows.to_hash:

```
{:email=>"Matching@asd.asd", :first_name=>"First", :last_name=>"Last"}
{:email=>"Notmatching@asd.asd", :first_name=>"Matching", :last_name=>"Name"}
{:email=>"asdasdasdasd@asd.asd", :first_name=>"asd", :last_name=>"asd"}
```

Another example from the console, which furthers my confusion:

```
> Record.find 14    # Record created by CSV
=> <Record id: 14, first_name: "First", last_name: "Last", email: "Matching@asd.asd", created_at: "2011-07-29 18:03:25", updated_at: "2011-07-29 18:03:25">
> Record.find(14).email
=> "Matching@asd.asd"
> Record.find_by_email Record.find(14).email
=> nil
```

-

**Updated with SQL output**

SQL generated by `Record.find_by_email Record.find(14).email`:

```
Record Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE "records"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 14]]
Record Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE "records"."email" = 'Matching@asd.asd' LIMIT 1
```

-

**Trying out the SQLite console**

```
sqlite> SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE "records"."email" = 'Matching@asd.asd' LIMIT 1;
# This one should have returned the CSV record, but it returns nothing
sqlite> SELECT "records".* FROM "records" WHERE "records"."email" = 'nomatch@asd.asd' LIMIT 1;
5|2|match|this|nomatch@asd.asd|2011-07-29 17:13:13.821972|2011-07-29 17:13:13.821972
```

-

**Adding model code, query results, CSV input**

Possibly the most exciting model known to man:

```
class Record < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :file
  attr_accessor :file
end
```

More results from the query:

```
sqlite> select * from records;
5|2|match|this|nomatch@asd.asd|2011-07-29 17:13:13.821972|2011-07-29 17:13:13.821972
9|3|first|last||2011-07-29 17:56:50.471766|2011-07-29 17:56:50.471766
10|6|first|last||2011-07-29 17:56:54.917432|2011-07-29 17:56:54.917432
17||First|Last|Matching@asd.asd|2011-07-29 19:43:23.843188|2011-07-29 19:43:23.843188
18||Matching|Name|Notmatching@asd.asd|2011-07-29 19:43:23.849001|2011-07-29 19:43:23.849001
19||asd|asd|asdasdasdasd@asd.asd|2011-07-29 19:43:23.852037|2011-07-29 19:43:23.852037
```

For good measure, the test CSV file:

```
email,first name,last name
Matching@asd.asd,First,Last
Notmatching@asd.asd,Matching,Name
asdasdasdasd@asd.asd,asd,asd
```

Comment: Please debug what `row.to_hash` contains inside the loop. `logger.info row.to_hash`.

Comment: @Casper: I edited the question with results from `logger.info row.to_hash` and another example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hmm. Add more debugging to the console: `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)`. What SQL does it generate for `Record.find_by_email Record.find(14).email`?

Comment: I added the SQL statements to my question. Thanks for helping me out with this.

Comment: What DB are you using? Can you go to the console of the DB and run the same SQL query there?..Everything looks OK so far. No clue why your Record class is not being returned. Do you have any special code in your Record model?

Comment: I'm using Sqlite. The SQL statements don't work directly in the sqlite console, either.

I experimented in the rails console by changing the record's email to "asd@asd.asd" and back to "Matching@asd.asd" and that made it work, so it is isolated to records created through the CSV. `Record.all` returns all the records as expected, so I'm guessing that they are stored in the DB fine. The Record model has an attr_accessible and attr_accessor, but that's all. Nothing exciting in there.

Comment: Please post the full code for the model just to be sure. Also when you tried to search for `Matching@asd.asd` in the Sqlite console..what does `select * from records` show? I'm trying to figure out if the `Matching` record is present the DB or not? So: when you read from CSV, is the 'Matching' record created in the Sqlite DB when you check it from the Sqlite console? Something is fundamentally screwed up somewhere here..or then maybe you are asking for trouble by running an "unstable" rc-version of Rails. Perhaps double-check with a 3.0-stable version instead?

Comment: Updated. The `Matching` record seems to be created correctly. I'll test it on a stable version and see how it goes. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be an encoding problem.

The email, first name and last name were thrown into SQLite as blobs, which I guess causes a problem or two. Adding `:encoding => 'u'` as an option for `CSV.foreach` fixed everything up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem. Remove all `attr_*` lines from your `Record` model. All `ActiveRecord` database fields are accessible by default. By adding `attr` fields you are effectively overwriting the default Rails accessors and that's why everything is acting weird.

Lesson to learn: when you think you have "nothing interesting" in your model...be very suspicious :) Good luck. Removing those lines should fix everything.

Comment: Ah, if only it was that easy. I went ahead and tested it out on a stable 3.0.9 app and blank 3.1.0rc5 app like you suggested. Using `Record.find_by_email` works as expected on the 3.0.9 app. So it looks like my problem lies in the release candidate. Thanks again for helping me through this. Off to the bug tracker I go.